# ClamAV finds a possible virus in Tor-browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/extensions/https-everywhere-eff@eff.org.xpi

According to ClamAV this file possibly contains a virus Status: PhishTank.Phishing.5378510.UNOFFICIAL Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Virus scanners often end up with false positives. Every Tor Browser update generally results in some antivirus taking some issue with the new version of Tor Browser.

If you downloaded the Tor Browser from a legitimate source, and if you verified the download to ensure that you got the correct file signed by the Tor Browser developers signing key, then it is safe to assume that it is not a virus.